# List of JS events in the WooCommerce frontend

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, javascript

Where could I find an exhaustive list of javascript events defined by WooCommerce. ( Events like "woocommerce_variation_has_changed" )

Answer (score 111, accepted):

On a hunt for the same I took a little dive into the JS source files.

## Woocommerce Javascript events

### Woocommerce Checkout JS events

```
$( document.body ).trigger( 'init_checkout' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'payment_method_selected' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'updated_checkout' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'checkout_error' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'applied_coupon_in_checkout' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'removed_coupon_in_checkout' );
```

### Woocommerce cart page JS events

```
$( document.body ).trigger( 'wc_cart_emptied' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'updated_wc_div' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'updated_cart_totals' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'country_to_state_changed' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'updated_shipping_method' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'applied_coupon', [ coupon_code ] );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'removed_coupon', [ coupon ] );
```

### Woocommerce Single product page JS events

```
$( '.wc-tabs-wrapper, .woocommerce-tabs, #rating' ).trigger( 'init' );
```

### Woocommerce Variable product page JS events

```
$( document.body ).trigger( 'found_variation', [variation] );
```

### Woocommerce Add to cart JS events

```
$( document.body ).trigger( 'adding_to_cart', [ $thisbutton, data ] );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'added_to_cart', [ response.fragments, response.cart_hash, $thisbutton ] );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'removed_from_cart', [ response.fragments, response.cart_hash, $thisbutton ] );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'wc_cart_button_updated', [ $button ] );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'cart_page_refreshed' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'cart_totals_refreshed' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'wc_fragments_loaded' );
```

### Woocommerce Add payment method JS events

```
$( document.body ).trigger( 'init_add_payment_method' );
```

### To bind listener to these events, use:

```
jQuery('<event_target>').on('<event_name>', function(){
    console.log('<event_name> triggered');
});
```

**F. ex.**

```
jQuery('body').on('init_checkout', function(){
    console.log('init_checkout triggered');
    // now.do.whatever();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what I was looking for, I will come back here if I find other events.

Comment: This is not working for me. I suspect my script needs to be made dependent on the woocommerce scripts,  but I don't know what they're registered as.

Comment: @Badger what more specifically isn't working? Which page are you working on, and have you checked that the woocommerce scripts are being loaded?

Comment: Nothing is logged to the console when I add something to the basket on the product page using the following code: `jQuery(function() {
 // Product added to basket
 jQuery('body').on('added_to_cart', function(){
  console.log('Item was added to cart');
 });
});` The scripts appear to be loading. I have enqueued my script to be dependent on 'woocommerce'

Comment: @Badger sorry I totally forgot to answer you. For others who might experience the same issue, by default Woocommerce does a full page reload upon add-to-cart event, hence the JS event never takes place. If you enable add-to-cart with AJAX in WC settings, you'll get the JS event too.

Comment: Can someone please add some description to each of the triggers. Specifically, I'm looking for an event that's triggered upon successful checkout - would I use - "init_checkout" or something else?

Comment: @SwimmingG basically successful (submitted) checkout or order comes with page redirection to the 'thank-you' page or so. Do you have custom behavior on this? Maybe [woocommerce_thankyou](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_thankyou/) action hook (php) or similar is what you need?

Comment: @ViktorBorítás thanks Viktor - ideally I'd be able to use a trigger that's just using javascript on the front end rather than working in php, if I can't do it with just js then I'll move onto what you've mentioned. Thanks so much :)

Comment: I am looking to trigger the stock look-up after updating the select menus externally unless I am going about this wrong. I need to pass the values to something in order to get a variation ID.

My thinking is that I need to trigger a refresh on the add to cart but I am not having any luck.

Answer (score 15):

> **To find a complete list of all events** *(and stay updated on any new
> ones added)* you can consult the .js files in the directory: `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend`

Below I report other events *(in addition to @jgangso's answer)*:

#### VARIATIONS

- `hide_variation` triggered when displayed variation data is reset
- `show_variation` triggered when a variation has been found which matches all attributes
- `woocommerce_variation_select_change` triggered when an attribute field changes
- `woocommerce_variation_has_changed` triggered when variation selection has been changed
- `check_variations` triggered:

  - when an attribute field changes
  - when reload variation data from the DOM
- `woocommerce_update_variation_values` triggered when variations have been updated
- `woocommerce_gallery_reset_slide_position` reset the slide position if the variation has a different image than the current one
- `woocommerce_gallery_init_zoom` sets product images for the chosen variation

#### CART FRAGMENTS

- `wc_fragments_refreshed` triggered when refreshing of cart fragments via Ajax was successful
- `wc_fragments_ajax_error` triggered when refreshing of cart fragments via Ajax has failed
- `wc_fragment_refresh` refresh when page is shown after back button (safari)
- `wc_fragments_loaded` triggered after the cart fragments have been loaded

#### COUNTRY SELECT (CHECKOUT)

- `country_to_state_changed` triggered when the country changes from the select field
- `country_to_state_changing` and `wc_address_i18n_ready` handle locale

#### SINGLE PRODUCT

- `wc-product-gallery-before-init` triggered before initializing all the galleries on the page
- `wc-product-gallery-after-init` triggered after initializing all the galleries on the page

#### PRICE SLIDER

- `price_slider_updated` triggered after price slider updated
- `price_slider_create` triggered after price slider create
- `price_slider_slide` triggered after price slider slide
- `price_slider_change` triggered after price slider change

Related answers:

- [Where to find a complete list of Javascript (JQuery) events that fire on the WooCommerce admin page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66626942/where-to-find-a-complete-list-of-javascript-jquery-events-that-fire-on-the-woo)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the full list references, you can go the interactive way and paste the below into your JS console and do the actions on the store, which you want to target, watch the console to see the effected events getting logged.

```js
jQuery(document.body).on(
  "init_checkout payment_method_selected update_checkout updated_checkout checkout_error applied_coupon_in_checkout removed_coupon_in_checkout adding_to_cart added_to_cart removed_from_cart wc_cart_button_updated cart_page_refreshed cart_totals_refreshed wc_fragments_loaded init_add_payment_method wc_cart_emptied updated_wc_div updated_cart_totals country_to_state_changed updated_shipping_method applied_coupon removed_coupon",
  function (e) {
    console.log(e.type)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the params in your code then here is an example

```
jQuery(document.body).on("wc_cart_button_updated", function (e, $button) {
    console.log($button);
});
```